How can I insert this symbol resembling a zeta?
I am an experienced Latex user. However, this looks like it is beyond my capabilities. I tried to use Detexfy, but it did not work either.
Please, does anyone know the name of the symbol below or how can I insert it in my .tex file? It looks like that is something from statistics and/or probability, as this symbol represents uncertain data. It resembles the Greek letter zeta.
I found this symbol in Sections 2 and 3 of https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/14/1/106#B24-symmetry-14-00106
Thanks in advance!


Where did you find it?

Sections 2 and 3 of https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/14/1/106#B24-symmetry-14-00106

I believe it is closer to a stylized \zeta

@LaTeXereXeTaL no, it is \xi. at least, that's the Unicode code point.

Don't look too deep in the shape of symbols; the document happens to use mathpazo and that's the shape used for the Greek letter xi. Just use \xi in your typescript.

It's a Greek lowercase letter \xi, not \zeta.
To use this particular shape of \xi under pdfLaTeX, you need to employ the mathpazo text and math font package. Under LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, be sure employ the unicode-math package and the TeXGyre Pagella text and math fonts.
Incidentally, mathpazo and TeXGyre Pagella are both clones of the Palatino font.

\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex % we're using pdfLaTeX
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{mathpazo}
\else % we're using either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
   \usepackage{unicode-math}
   \ifluatex % LuaLaTeX -- can use abstract font names
      \setmainfont{TeXGyre Pagella}
      \setmathfont{TeXGyre Pagella Math}
   \else     % XeLaTeX -- need to use exact filenames
      \setmainfont{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
      \setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
   \fi
\fi

\begin{document}
$\xi$
\end{document}


If you copy the character and paste it into a Unicode character identifier, it will identify the character for you. Searching for


returns
U+1D709 : MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL XI


This is a normal lower case xi (i.e. ξ) rendered in a particular font where the upper loop is much smaller than the lower one.
Don't overthink this, you should just use \xi, as you would for any other lower case xi.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

This is the correct answer.

Unicode math font texgyrepagella-math includes exactly this shape as \xi. You don't need to use an ancient PostScript mathpazo font.
\fontfam[pagella]

Test: $\xi$ or $$.

\bye


This is the \xi from Pazo math, although that’s obsolete and has several more recent forks.  (However, many of these change the \xi to a different shape.)  In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you could use:
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Or Palatino Linotype, Palatino, etc.
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

You could also change only the shape of \xi to this symbol with:
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase, range=\mitxi]


@Mico Whoops! Thank you: newpx and Asana Math both use the glyph from pxfonts instead.

+1 for the range=\mitxi suggestion. :-)

I'd recommend the detexify website:
https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html
It recommends me the \upxi symbol ($\upxi$). A search for this symbol shows this guide, with some font families I didn't know about:
https://math.ecnu.edu.cn/~jypan/Latex/Ref_Cards/upgreek.pdf

Welcome to TeX.SE.
